# Securing endpoint with JWT Token

Tags: rest-api, jwt

I have a requirement where I have integrated an external endpoint with Salesforce so that the data will be sent whenever the status of any account record is updated.
The POST call is working fine but we need to secure the endpoint with JWT token. I read that I need to create a connected app to do so but I havent created any connected app for the above REST call process and just a remote site settings for the endpoint did the trick.
Can anyone guide me how to do configure JWT token  with the endpoint.

Comment: Salesforce is doing a callout, so the 3rd party needs to implement JWT authentication mechanism. You as a calling client will generate JWT token and then permform the callout by passing token in Authorization header.

Comment: also as you are able to call the other service just by remote site settings means that api is public ( unauthenticated ). In order to use JWT you need to generate the certificate and follow above comment.

Comment: Thanks @PranayJaiswal, Can you please help me out with the process of generating JWT token in Salesforce. Thanks!

Comment: Well, your 3rd party needs to provide you with security key first. Then you can use this library to generate access token : https://github.com/salesforceidentity/jwt